# PHP Find Make/Model of vehicle from string

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, preg-match

Looking to create script that will extract from the string make and model of vehicle.
For ex. string "2005 Acura Tl" we need to get Make:Acura Model:Tl

So to do that we need to have myslq database of makes/models
I am creating database of car make/model in format:

```
   id|make|model
   0|Acura|Nomodel
   1|Acura|Tsx
   2|Ford|F150
```

then i need to get that data into php array, so after that i would be able to do preg_match:

1) Preg_match makes to string

2) Preg_match models from specific make to string

so from this string ""2005 Acura Tl""
we suppose to get id of model and id of make (ids in database)

Please help to figure out the right way to do that.

Comment: Will the year like `2005` will be always first in all strings?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is quite vague. Even if we try to generalise the problem and use regular expressions and preg_match, It might fail. You need to check and make sure that the following cases are satisified.

Cases:
1. will each line starts with only Year?
2. Will year be always 4 digits?
3. Will Make be always one word?
4. Will Model be always one word?
5. Will the delimiter between year,model and make is always a single space?

If all these cases are satisfied, then you might use explode() like this:

```
$str = "2005 Acura Tl";
$vehicle = explode(" ",$str)
echo "Year: ".$vehicle[0];
echo "Make: ".$vehicle[1];
echo "Model: ".$vehicle[2];
```